# Combine/merge lists by elements names

Tags: r, list, merge, element, named

I have two lists, whose elements have partially overlapping names, which I need to merge/combine together into a single list, element by element:

```
> lst1 <- list(integers=c(1:7), letters=letters[1:5],
                words=c("two", "strings"))
> lst2 <- list(letters=letters[1:10], booleans=c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE),
                words=c("another", "two"), floats=c(1.2, 2.4, 3.8, 5.6))

> lst1
$integers
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

$letters
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"

$words
[1] "two"     "strings"

> lst2
$letters
 [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j"

$booleans
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE

$words
[1] "another" "two"    

$floats
[1] 1.2 2.4 3.8 5.6
```

**I tried using *mapply*, which basically combines the two lists by index** (i.e.: "[["), **while I need to combine them by name** (i.e.: "$"). In addition, since the lists have different lengths, the recycling rule is applied (with rather unpredictable results).

```
> mapply(c, lst1, lst2)
$integers
 [1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j"

$letters
[1] "a"     "b"     "c"     "d"     "e"     "TRUE"  "TRUE"  "FALSE" "TRUE" 

$words
[1] "two"     "strings" "another" "two"    

$<NA>
 [1] 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 1.2 2.4 3.8 5.6

Warning message:
In mapply(c, lst1, lst2) :
  longer argument not a multiple of length of shorter
```

As you might imagine, what I'm looking for is:

```
$integers
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

$letters
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j"

$words
[1] "two"     "strings"   "another" "two"

$booleans
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE

$floats
[1] 1.2 2.4 3.8 5.6
```

Is there any way to achieve that?
Thank you!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can do:

```
keys <- unique(c(names(lst1), names(lst2)))
setNames(mapply(c, lst1[keys], lst2[keys]), keys)
```

---

Generalization to any number of lists would require a mix of `do.call` and `lapply`:

```
l <- list(lst1, lst2, lst1)
keys <- unique(unlist(lapply(l, names)))
setNames(do.call(mapply, c(FUN=c, lapply(l, `[`, keys))), keys)
```

Answer (score 3):

An update of [flodel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18539199/3474279) for `tidyverse` users:

```
list1 <- list(integers=c(1:7), letters=letters[1:5],
               words=c("two", "strings"))
list2 <- list(letters=letters[1:10], booleans=c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE),
               words=c("another", "two"), floats=c(1.2, 2.4, 3.8, 5.6))

input_list <- list(list1, list2, list1, list2)
```

We want to replicate the original desired output exactly twice for each element in the output list. Using `map2` and `reduce`, we can achieve that with a little bit more clarity than the base `R` solution involving `do.call`, `mapply`, and `lapply`. First, we declare a function that combines two lists by their named elements using `c()`, then we call our function on the input list via `reduce`:

```
library(purrr)

cat_lists <- function(list1, list2) {  

  keys <- unique(c(names(list1), names(list2)))
  map2(list1[keys], list2[keys], c) %>% 
    set_names(keys)  

}

combined_output <- reduce(input_list, cat_lists)
```

Which gives us what we want:

```
> combined_output

#> $integers
#>  [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
#> 
#> $letters
#>  [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" "a" "b"
#> [18] "c" "d" "e" "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j"
#> 
#> $words
#> [1] "two"     "strings" "another" "two"     "two"     "strings" "another"
#> [8] "two"    
#> 
#> $booleans
#> [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
#> 
#> $floats
#> [1] 1.2 2.4 3.8 5.6 1.2 2.4 3.8 5.6
```

Answer (score 2):

I will add my own solution which is  based on the `tapply` function.

```r
lst1 <- list(integers=c(1:7), letters=letters[1:5],
               words=c("two", "strings"))
lst2 <- list(letters=letters[1:10], booleans=c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE),
               words=c("another", "two"), floats=c(1.2, 2.4, 3.8, 5.6))

binded <- c(lst1, lst2) # and for list of lists Reduce("c", list(lst1, lst2))

tapply(binded, names(binded), function(x) unlist(x, FALSE, FALSE)) # double false for better performance
```

Answer (score 0):

I also use `grep`, don't know if it is better, worst, or equivalent !

```
l_tmp <- c(lst1, lst2, lst1)
keys = unique(names(l_tmp))
l = sapply(keys, function(name) {unlist(l_tmp[grep(name, names(l_tmp))])})
```