# combine list elements based on element names

Tags: r

How to combine this list of vectors by elements names ?

```
L1 <- list(F01=c(1,2,3,4),F02=c(10,20,30),F01=c(5,6,7,8,9),F02=c(40,50))
```

So to get :

```
results <- list(F01=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),F02=c(10,20,30,40,50))
```

I tried to apply the following solution [merge lists by elements names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18538977/combine-merge-lists-by-elements-names) but I can't figure out how to adapt this to my situation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
sapply(unique(names(L1)), function(x) unname(unlist(L1[names(L1)==x])), simplify=FALSE)
$F01
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

$F02
[1] 10 20 30 40 50
```

Comment: Great, your a life saver. What's the purpose of unname here, if I may ask ? Thank you.

Comment: @Chargaff, without `unname`, each vector has a name attribute, inherited from the list element name. Try it and you'll see it. Also, it's better to add `simplify=FALSE` above, to avoid gettin a matrix instead of a list. I'm editing the answer now.

Comment: Instead of `unname` you could add the option `use.names = F` in `unlist`. But both methods remove the original names of the vector...

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same result using `map` function from `purrr`

```
map(unique(names(L1)), ~ flatten_dbl(L1[names(L1) == .x])) %>%
  set_names(unique(names(L1)))
```

The first line transforms the data by merging elements with matching names, while the last line renames new list accordingly.