# In R, reorganize list based on element names (rbind and indicator variable)

Tags: r, rbind

I am trying to reorganize my data, basically a list of data.frames.
Its elements represent subjects of interest (A and B), with observations on x and y, collected on two occasions (1 and 2).
I am trying to make this a list that contains data.frames referring to the subjects, with the information on which occasion x and y were collected being stored in the respective data.frames as new variable, as opposed to the element name:

```
library('rlist')

A1 <- data.frame(x=sample(1:100,2),y=sample(1:100,2))
A2 <- data.frame(x=sample(1:100,2),y=sample(1:100,2))
B1 <- data.frame(x=sample(1:100,2),y=sample(1:100,2))
B2 <- data.frame(x=sample(1:100,2),y=sample(1:100,2))

list <- list(A1=A1,A2=A2,B1=B1,B2=B2)

A <- do.call(rbind,list.match(list,"A"))
B <- do.call(rbind,list.match(list,"B"))

list <- list(A=A,B=B)
list <- lapply(list,function(x) {
      y <- data.frame(x)
      y$class <- c(rep.int(1,2),rep.int(2,2))
      return(y)
})

> list
$A
      x  y class
A1.1 66 96     1
A1.2 76 58     1
A2.1 50 93     2
A2.2 57 12     2

$B
      x  y class
B1.1 58 56     1
B1.2 69 15     1
B2.1 77 77     2
B2.2  9  9     2
```

In my real world problem there are about 500 subjects, not always two occasions, differing numbers of observations.

So my example above is just to illustrate where I want to get, and I am stuck at how to pass to the do.call-rbind that it should, based on elements names, bind subject-specific elements as new list elements together, while assigning a new variable.

To me, this is a somewhat fuzzy task, and the closest I got was the `rlist` package. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18767575/combine-list-elements-based-on-element-names) question is related but uses `unique` to identify elements, whereas in my case it seems to be more a regex problem.

I'd be happy even for instructions on how to use google, any keywords for further research etc.

Comment: If you supply a few of the real data frame names you have, someone trying to help will be able to write a more accurate regex for you.

Comment: I thought leaving the regex issue at a more abstract level would de-clutter my question. Of course, stackoverflow proved to have really helpful people around, once again. I'll process your answer below and get back :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're doing a lot of gymnastics because you have a specific form in mind.  What I would suggest is first trying to make the data [tidy](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf).  Without reading the link, the quick summary is to put your data into a single data frame, where it can be easily processed.

The quick version of the answer (here I've used `lst` instead of `list` for the name to avoid confusion with the built-in `list`) is to do this:

```
do.call(rbind,
  lapply(seq(lst), function(i) {
    lst[[i]]$type <- names(lst)[i]; lst[[i]]
  })
)
```

What this will do is create a single data frame, with a column, "type", that contains the name of the list item in which that row appeared.

Using a slightly simplified version of your initial data:

```
lst <- list(A1=data.frame(x=rnorm(5)), A2=data.frame(x=rnorm(3)), B=data.frame(x=rnorm(5)))
lst
$A1
           x
1  1.3386071
2  1.9875317
3  0.4942179
4 -0.1803087
5  0.3094100

$A2
           x
1 -0.3388195
2  1.1993115
3  1.9524970

$B
           x
1 -0.1317882
2 -0.3383545
3  0.8864144
4  0.9241305
5 -0.8481927
```

And then applying the magic function

```
df <- do.call(rbind,
   lapply(seq(lst), function(i) {
     lst[[i]]$type <- names(lst)[i]; lst[[i]]
   })
 )
df
            x type
1   1.3386071   A1
2   1.9875317   A1
3   0.4942179   A1
4  -0.1803087   A1
5   0.3094100   A1
6  -0.3388195   A2
7   1.1993115   A2
8   1.9524970   A2
9  -0.1317882    B
10 -0.3383545    B
11  0.8864144    B
12  0.9241305    B
13 -0.8481927    B
```

From here we can process to our hearts content; with operations like `df$subject <- gsub("[0-9]*", "", df$type)` to extract the non-numeric portion of `type`, and tools like `split` can be used to generate the sub-lists that you mention in your question.

In addition, once it is in this form, you can use functions like `by` and `aggregate` or libraries like `dplyr` or `data.table` to do more advanced split-apply-combine operations for data analysis.

Comment: As long as my reputation does not allow for upvotes, I will leave my thanks here. I need more time to process your answer than you guys to write them!

Answer (score 2):

From the data you provided:

```
subj <- sub("[A-Z]*", "", names(lst))
newlst <- Map(function(x, y) {x[,"class"] <- y;x}, lst, subj)
```

First we do the regular expression call to isolate the number that will go in the `class` column. In this case, I matched on capital letters and erased them leaving the number. Therefore, `"A1"` becomes `"1"`. Please note that the real names will mean a different regex pattern.

Then we use `Map` to create a new column for each data frame and save to a new list called `newlst`. Map takes the first element of each argument and carries out the function then continues on with each object element. So the first data frame in `lst` and the first number in `subj` are used first. The anonymous function I used is `function(x,y) {x[, "class"] <- y; x}`. It takes two arguments. The first is the data frame, the second is the column value.

Now it's much easier to move forward. We can create a vector called `uniq.nmes` to get the names of the data frames that we will combine. Where `"A1"` will become `"A"`. Then we can rbind on that match:

```
uniq.nmes <- unique(sub("\\d", "", names(lst)))
lapply(uniq.nmes, function(x) {
  do.call(rbind, newlst[grep(x, names(newlst))])
})
# [[1]]
#       x  y class
# A1.1  1 79     1
# A1.2 30 13     1
# A2.1 90 39     2
# A2.2 43 22     2
# 
# [[2]]
#       x  y class
# B1.1 54 59     1
# B1.2 83 90     1
# B2.1 85 36     2
# B2.2 91 28     2
```

**Data**

```
A1 <- data.frame(x=sample(1:100,2),y=sample(1:100,2))
A2 <- data.frame(x=sample(1:100,2),y=sample(1:100,2))
B1 <- data.frame(x=sample(1:100,2),y=sample(1:100,2))
B2 <- data.frame(x=sample(1:100,2),y=sample(1:100,2))

lst <- list(A1=A1,A2=A2,B1=B1,B2=B2)
```