# Combine list elements (containing data.frames) based on element names in r

Tags: r, list, dataframe, rbind, do.call

Assume I have a list with 26 elements, with each element being named and containing a data.frame.

```
lst <- lapply(1:26, function(x) data.frame(AA = 1:5, BB = 1:5, CC = 1:5))
names(lst) <- letters
```

**How do I combine only select (specified) elements from this list into a new combined object (in this case, a data.frame)?**

- Ex: Let's say I want to only combine elements named "m" and "o" into a single data.frame.

  ```
    AA BB CC
  m  1  1  1
  m  2  2  2
  m  3  3  3
  m  4  4  4
  m  5  5  5
  o  1  1  1
  o  2  2  2
  o  3  3  3
  o  4  4  4
  o  5  5  5
  ```

I know there's a simply way to do this using `rbind` with either one of the `apply` functions or `do.call` or similar, but my various combinations of efforts have failed, and [similar posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18767575/combine-list-elements-based-on-element-names) I've been able to find have not helped.

Answer (score 1):

We may subset the `list` by named and use `rbind` with `do.call`

```
do.call(rbind, lst[c("m", "o")])
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R approach using `do.call`:

```
do.call(rbind, args = lst[names(lst) %in% c("m","o")])
```

Though, it creates a bit of a messy bunch of numbered row names:

```
    AA BB CC
m.1  1  1  1
m.2  2  2  2
m.3  3  3  3
m.4  4  4  4
m.5  5  5  5
o.1  1  1  1
o.2  2  2  2
o.3  3  3  3
o.4  4  4  4
o.5  5  5  5
```

This could be cleaned up in a second step using `row.names`