# Combine/merge lists by elements names (list in list)

Tags: r, list, merge

I have two lists, whose elements have partially overlapping names, which I need to merge/combine together into a single list, element by element:

My question is related to [Combine/merge lists by elements names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18538977/combine-merge-lists-by-elements-names), but the data structure in my example is more complicated and thus, the solution provided under the above mentioned link does not work in this case.

Here is a simplified toy example:

```
l.1 <- list(list(c(10,20), NULL),list(c(10,20,30), NULL), list(c(9,12,13), NULL))
names(l.1) <- c("a","b","c")

l.2 <- list(list(NULL,c(1,0)),list(NULL,c(1,2,3)))
names(l.2) <- c("a","b")
```

Thus, the data is of type "list in list" and looks like this:

```
# > l.1
# $a
# $a[[1]]
# [1] 10 20
# $a[[2]]
# NULL
# 
# $b
# $b[[1]]
# [1] 10 20 30
# $b[[2]]
# NULL
# 
# $c
# $c[[1]]
# [1]  9 12 13
# $c[[2]]
# NULL
# 
# > l.2
# $a
# $a[[1]]
# NULL
# $a[[2]]
# [1] 1 0
# 
# $b
# $b[[1]]
# NULL
# $b[[2]]
# [1] 1 2 3
```

**The result of merging both lists should look like this:**

```
# $a
# $a[[1]]
# [1] 10 20
# $a[[2]]
# [1] 1 0
# 
# $b
# $b[[1]]
# [1] 10 20 30
# $b[[2]]
# [1] 1 2 3
# 
# $c
# $c[[1]]
# [1]  9 12 13
# $c[[2]]
# NULL
```

I already adapted the solution given in [Combine/merge lists by elements names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18538977/combine-merge-lists-by-elements-names), but this seems not to work for this data structure.

Here is what I tried:

```
l <- list(l.1, l.2)
keys <- unique(unlist(lapply(l, names)))
do.call(mapply, c(FUN=c, lapply(l, `[`, keys)))
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inspired by josilber's answer, here we do not hard-code the length of the sublists and use `lapply` to create them in the result:

```
keys <- unique(c(names(l.1), names(l.2)))
setNames(lapply(keys, function(key) {
    l1 <- l.1[[key]]
    l2 <- l.2[[key]]
    len <- max(length(l1), length(l2))

    lapply(seq(len), function(i) c(l1[[i]], l2[[i]]))
  }),
  keys)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. See my follow-up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23493873/combine-merge-lists-by-elements-names-list-in-list-in-list

Answer (score 6):

You can use `lapply` operating on the keys to do this merge:

```
keys <- unique(c(names(l.1), names(l.2)))
setNames(lapply(keys, function(key) list(c(l.1[[key]][[1]], l.2[[key]][[1]]),
                                         c(l.1[[key]][[2]], l.2[[key]][[2]]))),
         keys)
# $a
# $a[[1]]
# [1] 10 20
# 
# $a[[2]]
# [1] 1 0
# 
# $b
# $b[[1]]
# [1] 10 20 30
# 
# $b[[2]]
# [1] 1 2 3
# 
# $c
# $c[[1]]
# [1]  9 12 13
# 
# $c[[2]]
# NULL
```

Comment: Should that be `keys <- unique(c(names(l.1), names(l.2)))`?  i.e. shouldn't there be a `c()` in there?

Answer (score 4):

Here you go in 3 lines:

```
out <- l.1
mnames <- intersect(names(l.1), names(l.2))
out[mnames] <- Map(function(a, b) Map(c, a, b), l.1[mnames], l.2[mnames])

#$a
#$a[[1]]
#[1] 10 20
#$a[[2]]
#[1] 1 0
#
#$b
#$b[[1]]
#[1] 10 20 30
#$b[[2]]
#[1] 1 2 3
#
#$c
#$c[[1]]
#[1]  9 12 13
#$c[[2]]
#NULL
```

Comment: Can you think of a version of your code where a,b,c do not have to be hard coded. I wonder what the performance of your code is compared to matthew-lundberg's solution. I am using the following input data to test the performance: `library(digest); l.1 <- rep(list(list(c(10,20), NULL),list(c(10,20,30), NULL), list(c(9,12,13), NULL)), 10000); names(l.1) <- sapply(sample(1:30000, 30000, replace=FALSE), digest); l.2 <- rep(list(list(NULL,c(1,0)),list(NULL,c(1,2,3))), 10000);
names(l.2) <- names(l.1)[1:20000]`

Answer (score 1):

This is a kind of a nested merge function which seems to produce the output you desire. I feel like there should be a more simple way but I can't think of one. It will prefer values from the first parameter, but will merge with values from the second parameter if there is a matching name or index.

```
nestedMerge<-function(a,b) {
    if(is.list(a) & is.list(b)) {
        out<-list()
        if(!is.null(names(a))) {
            for(n in names(a)) {
                if(n %in% names(b) && !is.null(b[[n]])) {
                    out<-append(out, list(Recall(a[[n]], b[[n]])))
                } else {
                    out<-append(out, list(a[[n]]))
                }
                names(out)[length(out)]<-n
            }
        } else {
            for(i in seq_along(a))
                if(i <=length(b) && !is.null(b[[i]])) {
                    out<-append(out, Recall(a[[i]], b[[i]]))
                } else {
                    out<-append(out, list(a[[i]]))
                }
        }
        return(out)
    } else {
        return(list(c(a,b)))
    }
}

#and now, use the function
nestedMerge(l.1,l.2)
```

Comment: Yeah, this is unnecessarily complex allowing for multiple levels of recursion and different ways of indexing. @thelatemail's solution is probably better and more understandable for this exact problem.

Comment: @rawr I must have changed the name of the function while testing. It should be calling itself. I've updated the code.

Comment: that's what I figured. great solution as always

Answer (score 0):

Here is an additional solution.  It uses `mapply` with `c` to combine the lists:

```
## get all possible names
l.names <- union(names(l.1), names(l.2)) 
## combine lists
r <- mapply(c, l.1[l.names], l.2[l.names]) 
## get rid of NULL entries
l.3 <- sapply(names(r), 
              function(x) r[[x]][!sapply(r[[x]], is.null)], USE.NAMES=TRUE)
```

I adapted this answer from answers found [on this SO question on merging two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519543/merge-two-lists-in-r) and [this R help question on how to delete null elements in a list](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/how-to-delete-the-null-elements-in-list-td4656622.html).

The first line gathers the names present in at least one of the two lists (i.e. all possible names).  The second line uses `mapply`, `c`, and list indexing with the previously gathered names to combine the lists, albeit with extra `NULL` entries present.  The third line gets rid of these `NULL` entries while preserving list names.

Note this answer does get rid of the `NULL` entry for list element `c`.