# Merging within lists and then across lists in R by Date

Tags: r, purrr

I have some lists which look like:

```
$SPA
           Date Formación bruta de capital fijo (real, índice) Consumo privado (real, índice) IRS 1Y
1Q80 1980-03-30                                             NA                             NA     NA
2Q80 1980-06-30                                             NA                             NA     NA
3Q80 1980-09-30                                             NA                             NA     NA
4Q80 1980-12-30                                             NA                             NA     NA
1Q81 1981-03-30                                             NA                             NA     NA
2Q81 1981-06-30                                             NA                             NA     NA
     Renta bruta disponible familias (nominal)
1Q80                                        NA
2Q80                                        NA
3Q80                                        NA
4Q80                                        NA
1Q81                                        NA
2Q81                                        NA

$GER
           Date IRS 1Y
1Q80 1980-03-30     NA
2Q80 1980-06-30     NA
3Q80 1980-09-30     NA
4Q80 1980-12-30     NA
1Q81 1981-03-30     NA
2Q81 1981-06-30     NA

$OTH
           Date Brent oil price (USD/barrel)
1Q80 1980-03-30                        38.25
2Q80 1980-06-30                           38
3Q80 1980-09-30                         33.4
4Q80 1980-12-30                        40.15
1Q81 1981-03-30                        38.35
2Q81 1981-06-30                        33.25
```

And also:

```
$FRA
        Date GDP....yoy. GDP....qoq.
1 1980-03-30        3.01        0.97
2 1980-06-30        1.81       -0.72
3 1980-09-30        0.70        0.15
4 1980-12-30        0.20       -0.20
5 1981-03-30       -0.45        0.32
6 1981-06-30        0.98        0.70

$GER
        Date GDP....yoy. GDP....qoq.
1 1980-03-30          NA          NA
2 1980-06-30          NA          NA
3 1980-09-30          NA          NA
4 1980-12-30          NA          NA
5 1981-03-30          NA          NA
6 1981-06-30          NA          NA

$ITA
        Date GDP....yoy. GDP....qoq.
1 1980-03-30          NA          NA
2 1980-06-30          NA          NA
3 1980-09-30          NA          NA
4 1980-12-30          NA          NA
5 1981-03-30          NA          NA
6 1981-06-30          NA          NA

$NOR
        Date GDP....yoy. GDP....qoq.
1 1980-03-30        3.75        1.31
2 1980-06-30        2.52       -1.16
3 1980-09-30        1.74        0.27
4 1980-12-30        0.81        0.40
5 1981-03-30        1.26        1.76
6 1981-06-30        2.21       -0.23

$SPA
        Date GDP....yoy. GDP....qoq.
1 1980-03-30          NA          NA
2 1980-06-30          NA          NA
3 1980-09-30          NA          NA
4 1980-12-30          NA          NA
5 1981-03-30          NA          NA
6 1981-06-30          NA          NA
```

I want to do 2 things:

1. In `lst1` I want to merge the `OTH` list with the `SPA` and `GER` list by `Date`. (This will eliminate the `OTH` list.
2. Merge `list1` and `list2`, again by `Date` but also not by their list names - i.e. so only `SPA` and `GER` will be merged since they are the only countries which appear in both lists.

Output: A single list consisting of just `SPA` and `GER` with `OTH` merged (in `list1`) and then both `SPA` and `GER` merged from `list1` and `list2`.

Expected output `GER` (first 2 rows):

```
           Date IRS 1Y                  Date        Brent oil price (USD/barrel)       Date           GDP....yoy. GDP....qoq.
1Q80 1980-03-30     NA                  1Q80 1980-03-30      NA                    1 1980-03-30          NA          NA
2Q80 1980-06-30     NA                  1Q80 1980-03-30      38.25                 2 1980-06-30          NA          NA
```

Data:

```
lst1 = list(SPA = structure(list(Date = structure(c(3741, 3833, 3925, 
4016, 4106, 4198), class = "Date"), `Formación bruta de capital fijo (real, índice)` = c("NA", 
"NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"), `Consumo privado (real, índice)` = c("NA", 
"NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"), `IRS 1Y` = c("NA", "NA", "NA", 
"NA", "NA", "NA"), `Renta bruta disponible familias (nominal)` = c("NA", 
"NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA")), row.names = c("1Q80", "2Q80", 
"3Q80", "4Q80", "1Q81", "2Q81"), class = "data.frame"), GER = structure(list(
    Date = structure(c(3741, 3833, 3925, 4016, 4106, 4198), class = "Date"), 
    `IRS 1Y` = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA")), row.names = c("1Q80", 
"2Q80", "3Q80", "4Q80", "1Q81", "2Q81"), class = "data.frame"), 
    OTH = structure(list(Date = structure(c(3741, 3833, 3925, 
    4016, 4106, 4198), class = "Date"), `Brent oil price (USD/barrel)` = c("38.25", 
    "38", "33.4", "40.15", "38.35", "33.25")), row.names = c("1Q80", 
    "2Q80", "3Q80", "4Q80", "1Q81", "2Q81"), class = "data.frame"))


lst2 = list(FRA = structure(list(Date = structure(c(3741, 3833, 3925, 
4016, 4106, 4198), class = "Date"), GDP....yoy. = c(3.01, 1.81, 
0.7, 0.2, -0.45, 0.98), GDP....qoq. = c(0.97, -0.72, 0.15, -0.2, 
0.32, 0.7)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame"), GER = structure(list(
    Date = structure(c(3741, 3833, 3925, 4016, 4106, 4198), class = "Date"), 
    GDP....yoy. = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), GDP....qoq. = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame"), 
    ITA = structure(list(Date = structure(c(3741, 3833, 3925, 
    4016, 4106, 4198), class = "Date"), GDP....yoy. = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), GDP....qoq. = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)), row.names = c(NA, 
    6L), class = "data.frame"), NOR = structure(list(Date = structure(c(3741, 
    3833, 3925, 4016, 4106, 4198), class = "Date"), GDP....yoy. = c(3.75, 
    2.52, 1.74, 0.81, 1.26, 2.21), GDP....qoq. = c(1.31, -1.16, 
    0.27, 0.4, 1.76, -0.23)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame"), 
    SPA = structure(list(Date = structure(c(3741, 3833, 3925, 
    4016, 4106, 4198), class = "Date"), GDP....yoy. = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), GDP....qoq. = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)), row.names = c(NA, 
    6L), class = "data.frame"))
```

Comment: if you are joining by date why do you have 2 dates? Why do you have the rownames in the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best solution, but the following code works. It uses the function `left_join` from the package `dplyr`.

Side note: Like user onyambu mentioned, having multiple date columns is not necessary. So my solution does have the dates only as rownames.

```
library(dplyr)
merge_oth <- function(element_to_merge, lst){
  short_lst = lst[-which(names(lst) == element_to_merge)]
  single_elem = lst1[[element_to_merge]]
  fin_lst = lapply(short_lst, function(x){
    dplyr::left_join(x, single_elem, by = "Date")
  })
  return(fin_lst)
}
merged_list <- merge_oth(element_to_merge = "OTH", lst = lst1)

merge_by_name <- function(list_1, list_2){
  keys = intersect(names(list_1), names(list_2))
  fin_lst = setNames(lapply(keys, function(key) {
    l1 = list_1[[key]]
    l2 = list_2[[key]]
    dplyr::left_join(l1, l2, by = "Date")
  }),  keys)
}
final <- merge_by_name(list_1 = merged_list, list_2 = lst2)
```

The resulting list contains the merged lists for `SPA` and `GER` and following your example the output for `GER` looks like this:

```
$GER
        Date IRS 1Y Brent oil price (USD/barrel) GDP....yoy. GDP....qoq.
1 1980-03-30     NA                        38.25          NA          NA
2 1980-06-30     NA                           38          NA          NA
3 1980-09-30     NA                         33.4          NA          NA
4 1980-12-30     NA                        40.15          NA          NA
5 1981-03-30     NA                        38.35          NA          NA
6 1981-06-30     NA                        33.25          NA          NA
```

I hope this helps. I took inspiration from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23483421/combine-merge-lists-by-elements-names-list-in-list).

Answer (score 1):

```
lst1_join <- lapply(lst1[-which(names(lst1) == "OTH")], \(x) merge(x, lst1$OTH, by = "Date"))

countries <- intersect(names(lst1_join), names(lst2))

final <- lapply(countries, \(x) merge(lst1_join[[x]], lst2[[x]], by = "Date"))
names(final) <- countries
```